# 8852be module for LTS kernel

Tags: wifi, realtek

I am compiling LTS kernel 6.1.23. This kernel do not have the RTL8852be. Now I am using [this](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89) link to compile the said driver. It compiles successfully but upon insertion, it throws an error:

```
rtw89_8852be 0000:57:00.0: MAC has already powered on
rtw89_8852be 0000:57:00.0: [ERR]pci config read 719
rtw89_8852be 0000:57:00.0: [ERR] pcie autok fail -22
rtw89_8852be 0000:57:00.0: failed to setup chip information
rtw89_8852be: probe of 0000:57:00.0 failed with error -22
```

This source code work perfectly fine with 5.x kernel.
Also, this module is integrated into 6.2.x kernel. But I want to stick with LTS kernel.

**Note** I have copied 6.2.10 kernel's rtw89 directory and compiled it against 6.1.23. Though it get compiled successfully but throws same error as mentioned above.

**EDIT 1** I compiled 6.2.10 itself which is having `rtw89_8852be` built-in. But still same issue is there.

Comment: The fact that the MAC is already powered on would suggest that the chip was already initialized – and that means you might already *have* a running kernel module before you insert your self-built one.